# (Game Maker Studio) How do I make a high score system?

Tags: game-maker

For my game, I want a way to make the game remember the top score. I know how to make the game save, I just need a way to save a high score.

This is my current system, that has not been working:

```
If next room exists >
If score is larger than health >
Set the health to score >
    highscore_add(global, score);
    highscore_value(health)
```

This has an output of nothing.

I would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`highscore_value`](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/social%20gaming/achievements%20and%20leaderboards/local%20high%20scores/highscore_value.html) takes different arguments from [`highscore_add`](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/social%20gaming/achievements%20and%20leaderboards/local%20high%20scores/highscore_add.html).

> ### highscore_value(place);
>
> **place**:  The place on the table (1-10).
>
> With this function you can retrieve the score value that has been stored in the high score list at the given position.

> ### highscore_add(str, numb);
>
> **str** The string (name) to attribute the score to
>   **numb**    The number (score) to add.
>
> With this function you can add a name and a score to the internal global high score list.

Your code

```
highscore_add(global, score);
highscore_value(health)
```

...attempts set and retrieve values using equal terms (`score` and `health`), which is a mis-use of the functions.  You are also using the `global` variable when you should be using a string.